# The graphics libraries are not installing using cabal

Tags: haskell

I just started to learn haskell few days ago. I install ghc version `8.10.2` and cabal version is

```
cabal-install version 3.2.0.0
compiled using version 3.2.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

I am try to install the graphics library for further practicing haskell. I tried to install three libraries(`OpenGL`, `gloss` etc). All three required `OpenGLRaw 3.3.4.0` and all three fails due to this libarary. The log file of fail is below

```
Preprocessing library for OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0..
Building library for OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0..
[  1 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.Groups ( src\Graphics\GL\Groups.hs, dist\build\Graphics\GL\Groups.o )
[  2 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.Types ( src\Graphics\GL\Types.hs, dist\build\Graphics\GL\Types.o )
ghc.exe: could not execute: C:/GitLabRunner/builds/2WeHDSFP/0/ghc/ghc/inplace/mingw/bin/ld.exe
```